# DXRSDK_v0.09.01 can not run on visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, raytracing

I tried to run this sample code in release mode, but it fails to run because of the following message:

`Unhandled exception occurred (0x00007FF831F1A388, D3D12RaytracingHelloWorld.exe): Microsoft C ++ Exception: HrException, memory location 0x00000043891FF778. Occur`

This message may not be accurate because it is a translation of Korean into English. I do not know how to handle this. I would appreciate your help. If you would like to approach this issue, the following site address is [provided](http://forums.directxtech.com/index.php?topic=5860.0).

Comment: What sample code? How did you build it?

Comment: I just placed a site link. Sample code related to ray tracing. [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yaK1e59-oAA] This site address is related to the results of the execution.

Comment: I would guess that HrException means it got an unexpected HRESULT from one of the APIs. Can you track down the line that's throwing the exception, and can you see what the error code is or what's causing it to be thrown?

Comment: I would expect it to be down to one of the pre-requistis not being fulfilled. The first says you need WIndows 10 with the April 2018 update (builds 1803). Are you using a Nvidia Volta card? I don't think it's possible to help from here without more details.

Comment: Does the debug build work?

Comment: + msg 0x00007ff7fd969ea0 L "Error: could not enable Experimental Shader Models. \ n" const wchar_t *

Comment: yes debug is working

Comment: @RoopeshKumarRamesh Dude, what did you do?

Comment: I am using windows 10 and using GEFORCE GTX 1080.

Comment: @ doctorlove somebody help

Comment: Error: Could not activate experiment shader model.
Exception occurred (0x00007FF831F1A388, D3D12RaytracingHelloWorld.exe): Microsoft C ++ Exception: HrException, memory location 0x000000560F4FECE8.
Create unhandled exception (0x00007FF831F1A388, D3D12RaytracingHelloWorld.exe): Microsoft C ++ Exception: HrException, memory location 0x000000560F4FECE8.

Comment: why experiment shader model not active...?

Comment: From your link, it looks like you need 1) an up-to-date Windows 10 build, i.e. not just Windows 10 but the April feature pack or later; 2) either a video driver that supports the experimental shader model - which sounds like it needs a newer NVidia card than you have - or their Raytracing Fallback Layer.

Comment: @Rup My Windows is a April feature pack. 2) I do not know. Do you mean you need a better graphics card?

Comment: From [this NVIDIA blog](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/introduction-nvidia-rtx-directx-ray-tracing/) it sounds like you need a card with NVidia's Volta architecture, and Wikipedia says that Geforce 10 does not have Volta. So I think yes, if you want to do this in hardware you need a newer graphics card. But I'd guess that the Raytracing Fallback Layer in your original link will implement this in software. But I've never tried any of this.

Comment: @Rup Thank you for answer! This problem has been solved by allowing the "developer settings" in Windows 10!